# How to get input from URL fragment?

Tags: php

I am working with `imagecreate`, here is my code:

```
<?php
$my_img = imagecreate( 200, 80 );
$background = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 0, 0, 255 );
$text_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 255, 255, 0 );
$line_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 128, 255, 0 );
imagestring( $my_img, 4, 30, 25, "Santosh", $text_colour );
imagesetthickness ( $my_img, 5 );
imageline( $my_img, 30, 45, 165, 45, $line_colour );

header( "Content-type: image/png" );
imagepng( $my_img );
imagecolordeallocate( $line_color );
imagecolordeallocate( $text_color );
imagecolordeallocate( $background );
imagedestroy( $my_img );
?>
```

Well, the dimensions passed to the imagecreate is hardcoded that I don't want to. I want the dimensions to be taken from the URL. I know I can use something we call `_GET` to do so. But that will make the url something like: `script.php?h=100&w=200`. But I want to something like: `script.php/100/200`.

So, how do I get input from URL fragment?

Comment: You'll have to pull apart $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] yourself with regular expressions or explode, the `function parse_url()` is very handy here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can strip out the script name and explode it into parameters as follows

```
$extra_path = str_replace($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],'',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$parts = explode('/',$extra_path);
```

This would then give you

```
$parts = array(
   '100',
   '200'
);
```

Comment: I think this will give error when multiple fragments are passed. e.g. what if I later want to use /g/ for a grayscale image?

Comment: Or maybe not! parts are stored in an array! I'm so stupid. :P

Comment: Yep, as long as you keep the order of your params consistent then it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) to access the URI that the user requested.

Comment: Why does documentation says **removed**?

Comment: `$HTTP_SERVER_VARS` is depreciated, `$_SERVER` is still fine

Comment: `$HTTP_SERVER_VARS` is removed. It was replaced by `$_SERVER`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull apart `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` with regular expressions or explode, the function `parse_url()` is very handy here...

```
if(preg_match('%/(?P<width>\d+)/(?P<height>\d+)(/|\z)%', parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],PHP_URL_PATH),$dimensions))
{
  var_dump($dimensions['width']);
  var_dump($dimensions['height']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` as described at
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php